# FastAPI (Python) Why I get "Unsupported upgrade request." with POST request?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have similar apps on Flask and FastAPI.
When I do this curl requests with Flask, that is all right:

Without TLS:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"method": "account.auth"}' http://X.X.X.X:5050/

{"error":0,"result":{"token":"XXX"}}
```

With TLS:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"method": "account.auth"}' https://example.com:8443/api/

{"error":0,"result":{"token":"XXX"}}
```

!!! But with FastAPI I get another result:

Without TLS:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"method": "account.auth"}' http://X.X.X.X:5050/

{"error":0,"result":{"token":"XXX"}}
```

With TLS:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"method": "account.auth"}' https://example.com:8443/api/

Unsupported upgrade request.
```

How to fix problem with "Unsupported upgrade request."? And what is it? Flask are working with it normally.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when launching the server for FastAPI?

Comment: @JasonRebeloNeves Yes, this: WARNING:  Unsupported upgrade request.
But I can't find the same situations in Google with POST, not with websockets.

Comment: Are you using websockets?

Comment: @JasonRebeloNeves No. Just POST request

Comment: If the answer I just posted doesn't help, it might be related to misconfiguration elsewhere, in which case more info will *probably* be required, at least from my perspective.

Comment: @JasonRebeloNeves Yes, It is work. Thank you

Comment: @JasonRebeloNeves Okay, It is work. But I get new error with uvicorn[standard]: error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0' How to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This same issue usually seems to arise from incomplete `uvicorn` installations, but is usually related to websockets.

A solution for this issue *might* be to reinstall `uvicorn` with the recommended ([by FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually/#deploy-manually)) extras:

```sh
python3 -m pip uninstall uvicorn
python3 -m pip install uvicorn[standard]
```

Comment: Okay, It is work. But I get new error with uvicorn[standard]:
error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0'

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem using java to access the api. The solution was to set HTTP Request to 1.1

```
var httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
             .uri(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8000/jobs"))
             .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
             .GET()
             .build();
```

Comment: thanks! That fixed it for me, too. I had to access a third party Python REST service and could not connect, always this strange "Unsupported upgrade request." error. Switching to Http 1.1 made it work immediately.
I found this statement about HttpClient: "HttpClient will use HTTP/2 by default. It will also automatically downgrade to HTTP/1.1 if the server doesn't support HTTP/2." but this does not seem to work with Python servers.