# Problem using POST in java.net.http.HttpRequest

Tags: httprequest, httpclient, fastapi

This code snippet does not seem to properly set the headers, or the body of the message.

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8001/test/"))
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonInputString))
    .build();
```

I've use Pythons FastAPI to set up a simple web service:

```
# Start with: uvicorn simle_ws:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8001
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Dataset(BaseModel):
    key: str
    value: float


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/test/")
async def test(dataset: Dataset):
    return dataset
```

It works with curl:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
    'http://localhost:8001/test/' \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{"key": "age","value": 43}'
```

{"key":"age","value":42.0}

It works with the pre java 11 methods:

```
@Test
void testPree11() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8001/test/");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    String jsonInputString = """
        {
            "key": "age",
            "value": 42
        }
        """;
    try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String responseLine;
        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(responseLine.trim());
        }
        assertEquals(200, con.getResponseCode());
        String expected = """
                {"key":"age","value":42.0}
                """;
        assertEquals(expected.trim(), response.toString().trim());
    }
}
```

But it does not work with the post java 11 methods:

```
@Test
void testPost11() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    String jsonInputString = """
        {
          "key": "age",
          "value": 42
        }
        """;
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8001/test/"))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonInputString))
            .build();

    HttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = HttpClient.newBuilder();
    HttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
    String expected = """
        {"key":"age","value":42.0}
        """;
    assertEquals(expected.trim(), response.body().trim());
}
```

The status code is 422 and the response is:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
          "type": "missing",
          "loc": [
            "body"
          ],
          "msg": "Field required",
          "input": null,
          "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76395059/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: That is the example I used to show that it works with the old java methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: the HTTP versions should be set to 1.1 and the path should not contain the "/" at the end. Thus it works with the HttpRequest defined as follows instead:

```
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8001/test"))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonInputString))
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got status code 307 but I added a followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL) and now it works.

Comment: @JohanWalter would you consider upvoting or accepting the answer since it helped solve your question? Thank you

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote posts.